# Not result on SSLSocket getInputStream().

Tags: java, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I'm trying to connect to the server via the HTTPS protocol with SSLSocket. In the browser, the response is normal, but my code does not get answer. If somebody has solution, please help me! Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String urlString = "https://host";
    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    Security.addProvider(
            new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

    SSLSocketFactory factory = null;
    try {
        factory = ooooo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SSLSocket socket =
            (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(url.getHost(),8443);
    socket.setNeedClientAuth(true);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(
                            socket.getOutputStream())));

    socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {
        @Override
        public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent handshakeCompletedEvent) {
            System.out.println(handshakeCompletedEvent.getSession());
        }
    });

    socket.startHandshake();
    write(out);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close()
    out.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket gets stuck when doing readLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7757544/7748072) . This is asked sometimes, in fact, calling readLine() you are assuming you will receive lines, which might not be the case. Reading bytes instead, you are not assuming anything, and you are sure to read them (or handle correctly the Exceptions, and an empty read buffer).

Answer (score 0):

Here helper functions!

```
private static void write(PrintWriter out){
    out.println("GET ... HTTP/1.1");
    out.println("Host: host");
    out.println("Connection: keep-alive");
    out.println("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    out.println("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1");
    out.println("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36");
    out.println("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
    out.println("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
    out.println("Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
    out.println();
    out.flush();
}

private static SSLSocketFactory ooooo() throws Exception {
    String clientPassword = "123";
    String clientCertificatePath = "my_cert.pfx";
    String trustStorePath = "cacerts";
    String trustStorePassword = "changeit"; // default trust store password

    KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(clientCertificatePath), clientPassword.toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(clientStore, clientPassword.toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(trustStore);
    TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());

    SSLSocketFactory lSchemeSocketFactory=sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    return lSchemeSocketFactory;
}
```